# Expected a value of type 'FutureOr<LinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

Tags: mysql, laravel, flutter

Estoy programando en flutter y api en laravel.
Mi problema es que funciona bien al momento de cambiar los datos en la base de datos, pero se me para detiene la aplicacion y me sale este error

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'FutureOr<LinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 121:3       castError
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 529:12  cast
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/classes.dart 193:14     as_FutureOr
packages/app_practica/provider/tickets_provider.dart 51:5                         editComment
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 784:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 813:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 584:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 657:7                                         callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 177:15               <fn>
```

Aqui llamo al provider

```
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                 child: Text('Aceptar'),
                 onPressed: () async {
                  var comment = comentarioCtrl.text != null ? comentarioCtrl.text :'';
                  await TicketsProvider().editComment(
                        widget.id,
                        widget.asunto,
                        widget.descripcion,
                        widget.fecha,
                        comment,
                        widget.estado); // aqui llamo al provider
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                 },
                  
                 ),
              )
```

Aqui el provider que me funciona bien, porque cuando se ejecuta y vuelvo mysql los datos se cambian, funciona bien pero la aplicacion flutter se detiene, y tira ese error

```
  
  Future<LinkedHashMap<String,dynamic>> editComment(
    int id,
    String asunto,
    String descripcion,
    String fecha,
    String comentario,
    int estado,
  ) async {
    var respuesta = await http.put(Uri.parse(apiURL+'/tickets/'+id.toString()),
    headers: <String,String>{
      'Content-type':'application/json',
      'Accept':'application/json'
    },
    body:jsonEncode(<String,dynamic>{
      'asunto': asunto,
      'descripcion': descripcion,
      'fecha': fecha,
      'comentario':comentario,
      'estado': estado,
    })
    
    );
    return json.decode(respuesta.body);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola Mauro, bienvenido, tanto el código como los mensajes de error, deben estar en formato texto, no en imágenes, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, de esa forma lograrás que sea mejor recibida y evitarás recibir votos negativos. mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Pregunto porque no se entiende bien: en vez de _Mi problema es que funciona bien al momento de cambiar los datos en la base de datos, pero se me para detiene la aplicacion y me sale este error_, ¿en realidad debería ser _Mi problema es que funciona bien, pero al momento de cambiar los datos en la base de datos se detiene la aplicación y me sale este error_? Así como está ahora redactado, no se entiende cuándo es que para la aplicación.